# Does Hibernate Search work on fields annotated with JPA Converter

Tags: hibernate-search

I am storing few fields as JSON using JPA Converter annotation, does Hibernate Search provide support for indexing/searching these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate Search doesn't see the "converted" side of your properties (in this case, the JSON).

If you have this:

```java
@Convert(class = MyJsonConverter.class)
private MyObject myObject;
```

Then all Hibernate Search will see is an instance of `MyObject`. You can use `@Field` or `@IndexedEmbedded` as you would with any other property.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column(name="address")    
@Convert(class = AddressConverter.class)
private Address fieldAddress;
```

If you convert your object to String for example. You can use something like with CriteriaBuilder

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<SomeObject> query = cb.createQuery(SomeObject.class);
        Root<SomeObject> from = query.from(SomeObject.class);
        query.select(from).where(cb.equal(root.get("fieldAddress").as(String.class), "address in string"));
```

If you using Spring Data JPA, your way is using @Query

```
@Query(select * from SOME_TABLE where ADDRESS = ?1, nativeQuery = true)
List<SomeObject> findAllByMyObj(String address);
```

P.S. If you using Metamodel and you should to save consistent of your Query(check the documentations [Hibernate JPA static metamodel generator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html)), it would looks like

```
query.select(from).where(cb.equal(root.get(SomeObject_.fieldAddress).as(String.class), "address in string"));
```